# Does JPQL supports SUM and arithmetic functions on the same fields in a query?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql

My query is like:

```
select sum(m.value * m.currency) from bill m
```

It fails and gives me this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while
>   creating a query in EntityManager: Exception Description: Syntax error
>   parsing the query syntax error at [*].

I'm using eclipselink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specifications defines the SUM expression as the following:

```
aggregate_expression ::=
  { AVG | MAX | MIN | SUM } ([DISTINCT] state_field_path_expression) |
  COUNT ([DISTINCT] identification_variable | state_field_path_expression |
         single_valued_object_path_expression)
```

So no, your query isn't valid JPQL. HQL (the Hibernate JPQL variant) supports it, though.

Answer (score 0):

This query should be supported in the latest EclipseLink version (or anything after 2.2 most likely).  What version are you using?